# Upper bound in an integral with exponential

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

I'm looking to find an upper bound on the following integral

$$\int_0^\infty K(u)S(t-u)du\,, $$

where 
$$ K(u) = e^{-u}(u-u^2/2), $$

and $ S(t) < C$ for some constant $C$.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the fact that since $S(t)<C$, we can use the estimate that $$\int_{0}^\infty K(u)S(t-u)du<|C|\,|\int_0^\infty e^{-u}(u-u^2/2)du|\leq|C|\int_0^\infty |K(u)|du$$

Now to finish your proof, you have to show that $\int_{0}^\infty |e^{-u}(u-u^2/2)|du$ exists and is finite. 
Edit: Consider the derivative of $\frac{1}{2}e^{-u}u^2$ and the limit for $u\to\infty$.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty K(t) dt = 0$. So something is not right because the integral can be positive too.

Comment: $$\int K(t)dt=\frac{1}{2}t^2 e^{-t}$$

Comment: I would say your proof would be true if we had the absolute values: $\left|\int_{0}^\infty K(u)S(t-u)du\right|\le \int_{0}^\infty |K(u)||S(t-u)|du<C\int_0^\infty |e^{-u}(u-u^2/2)|du$

Comment: But it is right, since $\int_0^\infty K(u) S(t-u)du\leq|\int_{0}^\infty K(u) S(t-u)du|$ (We Always have that $x\leq |x|$)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!